# How to change color of statusbar and navigation bar according to orientation changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to change status bar and navigation bar color according to app's orientation. e.g.

- Set `status bar` and navigation color to `Pink` when orientation is set to portrait.
- Set status bar and navigation color to "Yellow" when orientation is set to landscape. Change `AppBar` title to "LANDSCAPE" when app's orientation is set to landscape. And also change `AppBar` title to "PORTRAIT" when app's orientation is set to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried layoutBuilder?

```
LayoutBuilder(
 builder:(context,constraint){
  if(constraint.maxWidth < 600){
     //Your thing to do here when goes to portrait
   }else{
     //Your thing to do here when goes to landscape
  }
 //or you can change on the if function to DiviceOrietation.portait or landcape
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `OrientationBuilder` to listen orientation changes
and `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: color, systemNavigationBarColor: color));` to apply color

see full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          _updateStatusBarColor(orientation);
          // your layout
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateStatusBarColor(Orientation orientation) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final color = orientation == Orientation.portrait ? Colors.pink : Colors.yellow;
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: color, systemNavigationBarColor: color));
    });
  }
}
```

[image]